# CSS Float bullest list items, clearing float after x elements IE7 issues

Tags: asp.net, css, internet-explorer-7

[image]So I have a footer made up of a list, these are floating left and after 5 items I want a new line started.

This works  in all browsers but not in IE7.

So what I have done is that on the 6 item i.e. first item on second line is added a class..

```
        .liClearLeft        { clear: left;}
```

The problem is that IE7 even though the second line is floating left, the height is off and they are not aligned vertically the same, it seems to depend on the height of the 1st row. So I am guessing I am wondering how in IE7 do I get rows to be aligned vertically as well ?

Code

```
<div id="footerContainer" class="clearfix">
<div class="container">
    <div id="footerMainMenu" class="clearfix">
            <asp:Repeater ID="footerMenuRepeater" runat="server" onitemdatabound="FooterMenuRepeaterItemDataBound">
                <HeaderTemplate>
                    <ul id="mainMenuList">
                </HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <li class="footerParentSubLists <%# ((FooterMenuItem)Container.DataItem).MenuTitleBoldClass %> <%# Container.ItemIndex == 5 ? "liClearLeft" : string.Empty %>">
                        <div id="footerMenuDiv">
                           <a class="footerMenuHeader" href='<%# ((FooterMenuItem)Container.DataItem).CallToActionLink %>'><%# ((FooterMenuItem)Container.DataItem).Title %></a>
                        </div>
                        <asp:Repeater ID="subItemRepeater" runat="server">
                            <HeaderTemplate>
                                <ul class="footerChildSubList">
                            </HeaderTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <li><a class="footerMenuItems <%# ((FooterMenuItem)Container.DataItem).ArrowClass %>" href="<%# ((FooterMenuItem)Container.DataItem).CallToActionLink %>"><%# ((FooterMenuItem)Container.DataItem).Title %></a>
                                </li>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <FooterTemplate>
                                </ul>
                            </FooterTemplate>
                        </asp:Repeater>                
                    </li>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    </ul>
                </FooterTemplate>
          </asp:Repeater> 
    </div>
```

CSS :

```
  .footerParentSubLists {
       float: left; 
       width: 170px; 
       max-width: 170px; 
       margin-right: 20px !important;
   }
   .footerChildSubList { 
        margin: 0px;
        position: relative;
   }
```

Comment: Can you share the HTML code as well please ?

Comment: Added the code and mark up

Comment: Could you make a jsfiddle with all the code and css? You posted only a part of it.It could be useful in order to answer

Comment: I have added Image of the issue in IE7 as you can see the floating align issue on the second row of my list. Ideally i would want the the "About" lined up with "Contact"

Comment: The raw template isn't terribly useful.  We need the generated HTML.

Comment: Should use display: inline-block for li's instead of them floating left.

Comment: @StevieB - When you have to support non-standards compliant browsers (old IE versions) you can save yourself a lot of complexity by just using TABLEs for layout. While mark-up absolutists would crucify me if I wrote an answer using the TABLE tag for layout, it still gives the best (read: simplest) legacy layout support. Even the atrocious ALIGN and VALIGN attributes on the TDs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution that seems to work for IE7 is to add a "row" `li` and `ul` around every five `footerParentSubLists`. You can see the effect [in this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WKkT3/15/). Which uses this test code:

**HTML**

```
<ul id="mainMenuList">
    <li> <!-- row 1  -->
        <ul>
            <li class="footerParentSubLists">
                <div>
                   <a class="footerMenuHeader">Header 1</a>
                </div>
                <ul class="footerChildSubList">
                   <li>
                       <a>Sub 1.1</a>
                   </li>
                   <li>
                       <a>Sub 1.2</a>
                   </li>
                   <li>
                       <a>Sub 1.3</a>
                   </li>
                 </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="footerParentSubLists">
                <div>
                   <a class="footerMenuHeader">Header 2</a>
                </div>
                <ul class="footerChildSubList">
                   <li>
                       <a>Sub 2.1</a>
                   </li>
                   <li>
                       <a>Sub 2.2</a>
                   </li>
                 </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="footerParentSubLists">
                <div>
                   <a class="footerMenuHeader">Header 3</a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="footerParentSubLists">
                <div>
                   <a class="footerMenuHeader">Header 4</a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="footerParentSubLists">
                <div>
                   <a class="footerMenuHeader">Header 5</a>
                </div>
                <ul class="footerChildSubList">
                   <li>
                       <a>Sub 5.1</a>
                   </li>
                   <li>
                       <a>Sub 5.2</a>
                   </li>
                 </ul>
            </li>            
        </ul>    
    </li>
    <li> <!-- row 2  -->
        <ul>
            <li class="footerParentSubLists">
                <div>
                   <a class="footerMenuHeader">Header 6</a>
                </div>
                <ul class="footerChildSubList">
                   <li>
                       <a>Sub 6.1</a>
                   </li>
                   <li>
                       <a>Sub 6.2</a>
                   </li>
                   <li>
                       <a>Sub 6.3</a>
                   </li>
                 </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="footerParentSubLists">
                <div>
                   <a class="footerMenuHeader">Header 7</a>
                </div>
                <ul class="footerChildSubList">
                   <li>
                       <a>Sub 7.1</a>
                   </li>
                   <li>
                       <a>Sub 7.2</a>
                   </li>
                   <li>
                       <a>Sub 7.3</a>
                   </li>
                 </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
#mainMenuList {
    width: 950px;
}

#mainMenuList li {
    float: left;
}

#mainMenuList .footerParentSubLists {
    width: 170px;
    max-width: 170px;
    margin-right: 20px;
}

#mainMenuList .footerParentSubLists li {
    float: none;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
```

Comment: is correct - if you want every five to appear as "rows", you'll either have to wrap them in their own li so each row's height is defined by the tallest column, or you'll have to use JS to calculate the height of the tallest column in a row and apply it as a height to the subsequent columns.  Obviously just wrapping it with the "row" li is more elegant.